# Monero Applications Development

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui, mymonero, monero-research-lab

I'm a software engineer (Mobile/Native) with interest in cryptocurrency.

I would be interested in taking pet projects for monero, but, i've read recently that the jaxx guys halted the monero's wallet implementation due to lack of API support.

Makes me wonder, if the current state of monero is still too volatile for application level clients to be easily implemented.

Anyone knows anything related to this?

Cheers
Bruno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the bottom of [this CoinTelegraph article](https://cointelegraph.com/news/jaxx-cancels-monero-integration-cites-difficulties-working-with-community):

> The Jaxx team clarified that they halted work on Monero due to recent
>   protocol changes that caused difficulties, and because the integration
>   had gone significantly over time and budget, and was therefore
>   hindering development for the 1.2 release.

There was a large divide in the community, and I speculate that Jaxx did not fully understand how to work with Monero. The protocol change they are likely referring to is RingCT, which they probably did not understand the large impact the change would have when they first began development. If you are interested in an approach for a project, c789 listed several resources in their post. Furthermore, I would suggest asking technical questions in the Monero StackExchange, community consenss questions in Reddit, and developer help in the #monero-dev IRC. While people will not write code for you, they can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it was due to a lack of API support since documentation is available. I've been able to interact with the daemon and monero-wallet-rpc using cURL from the command line and with PHP. You can see available documentation here:

https://getmonero.org/getting-started/merchants

https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/

Answer (score 2):

Everything that Jaxx, and others, may need has been provided for development of wallets, as explained in this post:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5dsqrf/jaxx_monero_integration_update_3/da73yrj/

In this post, it is indicated that there are number of projects/tutorials, with detailed explanation, on how to do many things in monero:

- https://github.com/moneroexamples

However, many developers coming from Bitcoin, just expect copy paste their bitcoin code to magically work with Monero. Its not like this. Monero is 100% new code, and everything needs to be made from scratch for it. This requires some effort, which many don't want to take.